# upload a file to multiple locations

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Can we map web.xml to upload a file to multiple locations. I am able to upload file to single location but I am trying for multiple locations.
for example

```
<context-param>
    <description>Location to store  uploaded file</description>
       <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
       <param-value>
           C:\sample\pdf\
       </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: It is not quite clear to me where the "multiple" part comes into play in your example?

Comment: Is that a feature of a library you are using or a custom implementation?

Comment: I want for multiple location but only I can find is for single location.

Comment: I am using apache file upload jar files.

Comment: @AlokVerma write the files to multiple location with different context-params

Comment: thanks @happy I did the same uloaded file to 2 places from my JSP creating two diff context-params